# Problems in python combining the libraries datetime, pyplot and statsmodels

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, statsmodels

I have a strange problem using datetime in some plots when I import statsmodels. The first plot in the code is working fine, but something goes wrong if I try to plot again after importing statsmodels althoug I don't use it.

It seems that the second plot use the data until the day and doesn't takes into account the hours. Am I doing something wrong or it is a bug? How can I solve this?

Thank You.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

y=[datetime.datetime(2015,11,19,18,0,0),datetime.datetime(2015,11,19,19,0,0)]
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()

import statsmodels.api as smapi

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

The first plot is:
[First plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP89u.png)

And the second one:
[Second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QetOJ.png)

I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: you're going to have to show some example output to show what is wrong in the second case

Comment: I get the exact same result, whether I do the import of `statsmodels` or not.